# gsl error while Installing mlpy

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm trying to install `mlpy` and I get the following error.  I don't know where to start.  Does someone have any clue?

```
$ sudo easy_install mlpy-3.5.0.tar.gz
Password:
install_dir /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
Processing mlpy-3.5.0.tar.gz
Running mlpy-3.5.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-lQNT_3/mlpy-3.5.0/egg-dist-tmp-EPgtAi
mlpy/gsl/gsl.c:223:24: error: gsl/gsl_sf.h: No such file or directory
mlpy/gsl/gsl.c:224:39: error: gsl/gsl_statistics_double.h: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't have development package for gsl installed on your system. On RHEL/Fedora/etc. install gsl-devel, on Debian/Ubuntu/etc. install gsl-dev.

Comment: Thanks ... that appears to be the problem!

Comment: I've just encountered this problem, and correct package name for ubuntu/debian is: `apt-get install libgsl0-dev`

Comment: it's `apt-get install libgsl-dev` in Ubuntu 16.04