# Error installing mply library. Fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, c, linux

I'm trying to install the latest version of mply (3.5.0) on xubuntu (ubuntu 17.10):

1. download the .tar.gz
2. Unzipped it
3. `python setup.py build`. Here I get the **error** displayed below.
4. also tried directly `python setup.py install`. same error.
5. tried installing gsl library by downloading the latest version, and following all the steps in https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/jild13/2016/07/11/hello/. I have it installed in `/home/gsl`
6. still the same error
7. tried various other installations (`sudo apt-get install libgsl0ldbl`, `sudo apt-get install libgs123`, `sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev`). Nothing works.
8. tried copying the folder `/home/gsl/include/gsl` inside the `mply-3.5.0/mply/gsl` folder . this slightly changes something, because now I get fatal error: `gsl/gsl_sf_result.h: No such file or directory` (So it finds `gsl_sf.h`, but not `gsl_sf_result.h` (both these files are present inside the `/gsl/include/gsl` folder).
9. tried with
   `python setup.py build_ext --include-dirs=/home/gls/include/gls`
   still nothing
10. tried to copy the `/home/gsl/include/gsl` folder inside my `/usr/local/include`:

    `cp -R /home/gsl/include/gsl /usr/local/include/gsl`
    still nothing.

Help!

Error message:

```
gcc -pthread -B /home/lorenzo/anaconda3/compiler_compat 
  -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall 
  -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/lorenzo/anaconda3/include/python3.6m 
  -I/home/lorenzo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include 
  -I/home/lorenzo/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c mlpy/gsl/gsl.c 
  -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/gsl/gsl.o
mlpy/gsl/gsl.c:223:10: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf.h: No such file or directory
#include "gsl/gsl_sf.h"
```

Comment: Do you have development package for "gsl" installed on your system?

Comment: [Related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11494179/694576), if not a duplicate to it.

Comment: I have libgsl-dev installed.

Comment: And, I already tried the suggestions in that link, but nothing worked.

Comment: So what does `find / -name gsl_sf.h` tell you?

Comment: /usr/include/gsl/gsl_sf.h
/usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_sf.h
/home/lorenzo/gsl/include/gsl/gsl_sf.h
/home/lorenzo/.local/share/Trash/files/gsl.2/gsl_sf.h
/home/lorenzo/.local/share/Trash/files/gsl/gsl_sf.h
/home/lorenzo/.local/share/Trash/files/gsl.3/gsl_sf.h
/home/lorenzo/.local/share/Trash/files/gsl_sf.h
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied

Comment: Build `mlpy` : Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323877/python3-mlpy-installation-error-py-initmodule3-was-not-declared-in-this-scop/50330888#50330888 → Example `export CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 && python3 setup.py build && sudo python3 setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by re-installing gsl library using conda:
    `conda install gsl`