# Unable to install mlpy for Python in Debian WSL

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, machine-learning

I am trying to install mlpy3.5.0 but am unable to get it to work, due to a variety of errors.

I am installing it on Python 3.7.3 in a Debian WSL. I am doing this inside a VirtualENV, but have also tried installing it outside of it with the same issues occuring.

Originally when installing it, I would get an error due to lack of a GSL director. I used Miniconda3 to then install gsl but have reached a new roadblock:

Whenever I try to install it, whether it be through `python3 setup.py install` or `pip3 install machine-learning-py` (same result with mlpy) I receive the following error, followed by several more very similar errors.

```
mlpy/gsl/gsl.c: In function ‘__Pyx_GetException’:
mlpy/gsl/gsl.c:4027:24: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                        ^~~~~~~~
```

This gives me no insight and, sadly, I have reached the point of insane packages where Google provides no more results.

Any help or insights would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/mcfletch/pyopengl/issues/11
Might wanna look at this thread, it has very similar issues and might help I have no idea which one might be the answer for you.

I googled "has no member named ‘exc_type’;"  As this is your missing library.
Multiple sources sugggest installing Cython. (which comes up allot when I'm looking up this error)

Comment: Currently Cython version 0.29.14 is installed but has not seemed to do anything. I saw that thread, not sure if their solution fully translates though since I am not using the PyOpenGL code. 
Will look into finding where it is getting choked up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494179/gsl-error-while-installing-mlpy/11496798
"apt-get install libgsl-dev"?

Comment: @JasperLankhorst `libgsl-dev is already the newest version (2.5+dfsg-6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.` Makes me think it usually just comes with it? Correcting the code did not fix the issue as much of the gsl does not compile. It makes me wonder if I have an outdated version of something?

Will update as get more info. Thank you though

Comment: **Fix viewable here:** https://github.com/Psy-Fer/SquiggleKit/issues/31